# PCI Geomatica ATCOR error with RapidEye images

Tags: atmospheric-correction, geomatica

I'm doing atmospheric corrections to RapidEye images with ATCOR in PCI Geomatica 2014. However, there are serious salt-and-pepper type errors in the outcome bands 4 and 5. These errors only occur when haze removal is done as part of ATCOR. I would really need to do the haze removal as part of the atmospheric corection process.

Has anybody else come across to this error? Do you have any solutions to the problem?

Here is an example with RGB combination 5,4,3:

[image]